# great job at or great job in

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a note for the kids in my daughter's class. How do I say "you are doing a great job in kindergarten or great job at kindergarten?

Comment: I'm not trying to impress anybody I'm asking for help because I want to know the right way to write it.

Comment: We are giving them (kids) a present for the great job they are doing at school. It would be nice if you were more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for nothing

Comment: @Cascabel, I don't mean an answer... I'm not the right person to do it anyhow, and I think that you're right that both options work. Alex, here is a related post on [ELL.se] to start your investigation:  [good job on or in](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210449/good-job-on-or-in-something) . ELL is, I think, more suited to this question, as the stack over here would want the question to show the more technical vertices of the question in hand. Wherever you go, you should include at least some previous research. Do take the [tour]. Welcome, and cheers!

Comment: If I had to choose I suppose I'd use "in".  But I'd prefer a different wording.

Comment: To all: I just want to know if the wording is correct or not. It's not to impress anybody and I know that the kids are going to be happy with the present more than what the note says (their parents most likely will read the note and I don't want to look like a moron by writing the note the wrong way). I'm asking for my own benefit. English is not my first language and I thought this forum was to ask grammar questions. @cascabel had shown his/her true colors acting all high and mighty and that's not what I was looking for.

Comment: I would use "in", but they are both "correct" (just slightly infers different things), "Great job at Kindergarten" makes "Kindergarten" seem as though you are saying that your children did a "great job" in the "art of kindergarten" (like "you are masterful At your craft"), whilst the word "in" is more conventional, and, to my ears at least, depicts "kindergarten" not as an art, but a place, and that your children have done a "great job" at doing all the things that place entails. - Also, I agree this Stack is probably not the best place to ask this question, nevertheless, I hope all goes well!

Comment: I am not trying to make you feel bad, and if I did I sincerely regret it. I know how it feels  to be called out in public. Sorry. Can we reset?

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a controversial discussion so I accept some risk of disapproval by answering. Some account of your research (or at least your personal perception of the issue you are concerned about) would have helped to fit it to the site's purpose.

Nevertheless, I come here to enjoy my language at all levels from the simplest to the highest (where I lose competence and may only hope to learn). I wish to encourage people to use this fine site to enjoy English rather than to be discouraged by disparaging judgement or criticism, so here goes:

I find both statements to be informal and acceptable, composed in the right register for such a setting. There is no significant difference in meaning. The use of "great job", although not suitable for formal compliments, seems just right. When you say "in kindergarten" the emphasis is on what happens during the time the children are there. When you say "at kindergarten" there is little difference, apart from a hint that kindergarten is where they all go to do the great job.

Comment: @Cascabel I have commented in my answer to a newcomer that research is desirable. I do not believe that kindly answering the occasional simple question, particularly for new users who merely need guidance, will bring us a flood of trivia. Nevertheless I could be wrong; you have greater experience here so may be able to tell me I am mistaken in that respect? Amusingly, I am tempted to ask a question on the site about the meaning of the expletive or exclamation "Oh my Dog"

Comment: @Anton I think you were very brave to answer this question—most would pass by it in risk of getting downvoted, and indeed, most would not waste the time in writing a response whatsoever. For your bravery I will upvote your question and remove the downvote. This question, I agree, is not very fit for this stack, but to downvote your brave response to it, I think, is best not done. That is my humble opinion.

Comment: @Tom O’ Bedlam Thank you. And thank you Cascabel for your robustness. I am done with this. It is time to sleep.